# Multiple CSS3 animations in one hover class

Tags: css, animation

I want the picture to have an animation, and i want the text to have an animation.

This is what i got so far.

The class:

```
.post-image:hover{  
        animation: picanim 1s; 
        -webkit-animation: picanim 1s;
        -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
        animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
```

The animation:

```
@-webkit-keyframes picanim {
0%{opacity: 1; -webkit-border-radius: 5px; -mo-border-radius: 5px; border-radius: 5px;}
100%{opacity: 0.5; -webkit-border-radius: 20px; -mo-border-radius: 20px; border-radius: 20px;}
}
```

Now i want another animation to be inside the .post-image:hover class but when i do it, none of the animations work.

```
.post-image:hover{
     /*foto animatie */
     animation: picanim 1s;
     -webkit-animation: picanim 1s; /* Safari and Chrome */
     -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
     animation-fill-mode: forwards;
     /*text animation*/
     animation: textAnim 1s;
     -webkit-animation: textAnim 1s; /* Safari and Chrome */
}
```

Anyone got a solution?

Comment: Any JSFiddle? so we can interestingly write the answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you write the two CSS rules, the second will override the first so it can't work this way.

I can't see you HTML structure but i guess you have something like that :

```
<div class="post-image">
    <img src="image.jpg" alt="bla bla"/>
    <p>figcaption for the image</p>
</div>
```

Then you will be able to do something like this to animate both the text and the image

```
.post-image:hover img {
    animation: picanim 1s; 
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
.post-image:hover p {
    animation: textAnim 1s;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this answered my questions. Was pretty straight forward actually, just couldn't think of it.

Answer (score 0):

This is the answer. I couldn't add the text inside the animation.

```
<div class="post-image"> 
       <a href="#">
           <img src="http://velosofy.com/content/31.jpg" />     
           <p class="imgtxt">Title</p>
       </a>
</div>


.post-image:hover{
  picture animation
}

.post-image:hover .imgtxt{
  text animation
}
```